# BizTalk SSO API?

Tags: .net, biztalk, single-sign-on

I am building a custom application that provides a simplified user interface to an enterprise system. The users log in with NTLM, and I want my application to look up their User ID in the BizTalk SSO database and add their credentials to my outgoing requests.

Does anyone have any information on the BizTalk SSO API and how I might use it from a custom application that is not running through BizTalk?

Comment: Found a few namespaces like Microsoft.EnterpriseSingleSignOn.Interop... I'm doing some digging to see how to use the interfaces provided

Comment: Specifically, there's a method "LogonExternalUser" in the ISSOLookup2 interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at Richard Seroter's SSO tool which lets you lookup SSO settings http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/09/21/biztalk-sso-configuration-data-storage-tool. You could probably build a web service to handle the lookup and then call the web service based on the code from Richard's app and a few modifications.

Thanks,

Comment: Awesome find! We're comparing BizTalk SSO and Cyber-Ark's Password Vault right now, and since it looks extremely easy to harvest his SSOConfigManager class and use it in a web service, it looks like BizTalk's going to be getting some bonus points